# How to increase performance of FilteredList with many columns (9+)

Tags: java, performance, java-8, javafx-8

I have a TableView with roughly 5K rows and 9 columns. The TableView is backed by a SortedList and FilteredList. Every column can be used to filter the TableView via a ContextMenu and CheckBoxes.

```
public class ColumnFilter {
    public ColumnFilter(TableFilter filter, TableColumn column) { // ... }

    // ...

    public boolean filter(item) {
           ObservableValue<T> value = this.column.getCellObservableValue(item);
           List<String> selectedValues = // ... get values from selected CheckBoxes in the ContextMenu
           if(Objects.isNull(value) || Objects.isNull(value.getValue())) return true;

           for(String s : selectedValues) {
                if(s.equals(value.getValue().toString())) return true;
           }
           return false;
    }
}

public class TableFilter {
   public class TableFilter(TableView view) {
     this.view = view;
     this.filterList = new FilteredList<>(view.getItems());
     this.sortedList = new SortedList<>(this.filterList);
     this.sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
     this.view.setItems(sortedList);
  }

  // Create a filter for every column
   public void initialize() {
        columnFilters.clear();
        this.view.getColumns().forEach( column -> {
            columnFilters.add(new ColumnFilter(this, column));
        });
    }

   // ....

   // Set the predicate if a new filter item got added/removed
     public void filter() {
        this.filterList.setPredicate( p -> {
            for(ColumnFilter filter : this.columnFilters) {
                if(!filter.filter(p)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the performance gets extremely bad the more columns (=ColumnFilters) are added. For example, if I only have to filter one column it takes roughly a few milliseconds. With all 9 columns it takes up to 2 seconds.

How I can improve the performance? Or do I need to do the filtering without the FilteredList?

Comment: Okay guys I´m dumb af. Turns out that the performance overhead comes from retrieving the "selected" status of my checkboxes. this took nearly 90% of the time. After implementing a caching logic I got my performance down to a few ms.

Comment: Consider posting an answer with the details of your solution.